# LinkSys WRT54GL + AM200 in half-bridge mode - Setup guide recommendations?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, dd-wrt

I am basically looking for a good guide on how to set up my home network with this set of hardware.  I need:

- Dynamic DNS
- Firewall + port-forwarding
- VPN
- Wake-on-LAN from outside firewall
- VOIP would be nice
- QoS would be nice (make torrents take lower priority to other services when those other services are happening)
- DHCP
- Wireless + WPA2 security
- Ability to play multiplayer computer games

I am not a networking or computing neophyte, but the last time I messed with network gear was a few years ago, so am needing to dust off knowledge I kinda half have.

I have read that I should be wanting to set up the AM200 in half-bridge mode, so that the WRT54GL gets the WAN IP - this sounds like a good idea, but I'd still like to be advised.

I have read that the dd-wrt firmware will meet my needs (though I gather I'll need the vpn-specific build, which appears to preclude supporting VOIP), but I'm not wedded to using it.

My ISP supplies me with:

- a block of 8 static IPs, of which 5 are usable to me
- a PPPoA ADSL2+ connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following [this guide](http://jelnet.free.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?t=303), and referring to this other thread.  Except that I decided to use the Tomato firmware instead (one of the custom builds that offers OpenVPN), after reading that dd-wrt has a slow pace of development and has turned commercial.

Comment: The other thread is   http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/646845-help-with-linksys-am200-and-dd-wrt/

Comment: Tomato is http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato